# Landscape states X computers haven't contacted Landscape within the last 5 minutes, but they all did

Tags: cloud, landscape

Since a few days, Landscape (cloud) states that a number of computers haven't contacted Landscape in the last 5 minutes. But if I check those computers, the last ping time is actually one minute ago.

How do I get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Removed three of my computers from Landscape web page. Re-added them by ssh to them and

`sudo landscape-config`

with same configuration as before. All configuration is stored on the client and will be reused in this case, so you only need to provide the registration key.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what made the alert get stuck, but I found that it cleared out by disabling it for all computers and then re-enabling without having to redo any other config.

- Go to: **Landscape > account Title (next to 'Computers') > Alerts >
  ComputerOfflineAlert > Edit alert**
- Note what is checked here (it was just 'All computers' for me) and
  uncheck all the checkboxes.
- Click 'Change', you should see the alert cleared
- When it returns to the previous screen click 'Edit alert' again and place checks back in the same boxes as before
- Click 'Change' to put things back how they were

**2023 Edit:** I just had this happen again and the same fix didn't work, but restarting the Landscape client on the affected box did the trick.

Command:

```
sudo systemctl restart landscape-client.service
```

Comment: This answer might be the best, for now the issue hasn't returned after I deleted the computers in Landscape and re- inserted them. Next time it happens, I'll be sure to try disable and edit the alert.